# Seperation of images from one folder and putting them in another folder

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to load images from three folders and I want to differentiate them based on their name endings and put in new folders.
For instance some image ends with 1550_R_1, 1500_R_2 and so on and some in 1500_1, 1500_2 and so on.
How can I do that?
I am able to load all images.

```
**import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from shutil import copyfile
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
      
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
            
            if img is not None:
             images.append(img)
    return images
folders = [
    'C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Pictures/I3te_Reaktion',
    'C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Pictures/4te_Reaktion',
    'C:/Users/shiva/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK/Bildverarbeitung_Reaktion/Pictures/5te_Reaktion',
]
for folder in folders:
    images = load_images_from_folder(folder)

all_images = [img for folder in folders for img in load_images_from_folder(folder)]

print(len(all_images))
print(all_images)
i=150
for N in range(i):
  for filename in all_images:
     if any([filename.endswith(x) for x in ['1550_R_N.jpeg', '1550_N', '.jpeg','.jpg']]):
        cv2.imwrite(dir_name,filename)**
```

But this throws error as

```
 if any([filename.endswith(x) for x in ['1550_R_N.jpeg', '1550_N', '.jpeg','.jpg']]):
  File "C:\Users\shiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\isabella.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    if any([filename.endswith(x) for x in ['1550_R_N.jpeg', '1550_N', '.jpeg','.jpg']]):
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Hi! and welcome to stackoverflow! Your question si too broad and not well defined. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that you can limit your question to a concrete thing that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to do what you want to do. A regular expression is a pattern you define and try to match. So maybe your code would look something like this:

```
import re

[your existing code]

for filename in all_images:
    if re.match(r'.*_R_N.*', filename):
        print("Filename has '_R_N' in it, do something")
    else:
        print("filename doesn't have '_R_N' in it (so maybe it only has "_N" in it)")
```

The regular expression function `match` looks for a `_R_N` contained in the string. If it does not find the match, the return is `none`, so the `if` condition is not met. You can experiment with different regex patterns to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi, i tried it and I got the below error - 
  File "C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\shiva\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\isabella.py", line 47, in <module>
    if re.match(r'.*_R_N.*', filename):
  File "C:\Users\shiva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\re.py", line 163, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

To *fix* the error/exception; Change the function to keep the filename with the image as a tuple.

```
def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
       # if any([filename.endswith(x) for x in ['1500_R_1', '.jpg', '.jpeg']]):
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
            #cv2.imshow('Color image', img)
            if img is not None:
             images.append((filename,img))
    return images
```

Then unpack the name in the loop to use in the conditional:

```
for N in range(i):
  for filename,image in all_images:
     if any([filename.endswith(x) for x in ['1550_R_N.jpeg', '1550_N', '.jpeg','.jpg']]):
        ...
```